# Android Firestore - send notifications to all users using functions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been searching a lot about how to send notification to all users that have installed the application whenever there is a change in a Collection (that contains many documents). Like if there is a change in some document in that collection I have to send a notification to all devices. I don't mean using FCM, or notifying a specific user..

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario that you are describing involves two parts:

1. I’d say that what you are looking for it’s the implementation of [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) that are event-based triggered, so as mentioned in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) you can use the event [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#on-update) to detect changes on any document into a Collection by using wildcards as mentioned in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters). Take into consideration that there are not exclusive event driven implementation for Collections but you can apply the correct validation into the Firebase Function. To continue to the second step.
2. After some research I found that the FCM is able to use the Messaging Batch APIs in the Admin SDK, this is mentioned into [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/firebase-introducing-the-cloud-messaging-batch-apis-in-the-admin-sdk-2a3443c412d3) where there are several useful use cases to achieve your actual goal.